# NSURLConnection Never finish

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, error-handling, connection

i have the next code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:...."];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [""soapMessage"" length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [""soapMessage"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:20];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
[theConnection start];
```

Then sometimes, when i click a lot of times *(Just to try where can fail the app)* in my interface in the buttons assigned to start a new connection, the connection doesn't give a reply (I send the request but looks like is blocked after).

I would like to know **what is the use of "setTimeoutInterval"?** AND if there are some ways to **limit the time to wait one response?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the request started in the first place? You might be waiting for a response for a request that never started.

It appears you are not testing for `theConnection` being set to `nil`. also `theRequest` and `url` could also be `nil` if you run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you, but i make log of each part, and i sended it.
ANYWAY there are some method to LIMIT the time?

Comment: The logging was not in the code you pasted so there was no way to tell that you were logging for these things from your code.